# vector resize strange behavior

Tags: c++, stl, vector, resize

I have the following code. The interesting part is if I uncomment the resize() on vector, it is priting 10 numbers for an input value of 5. I am using eclipse with mingw and gcc on windows xp. Shouldn't the iterator go only for 5 elements?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
//#include "stdio.h"
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void print_coll(T t)
{
    typename T::iterator iter = t.begin();
    while (iter != t.end() )
    {
        cout << *iter << " ";
        ++iter;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    vector<int> numbers;
//    numbers.resize(size);

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < size; ++i ) {
        int r = (rand() % 10);
        numbers.push_back(r);
    }
    print_coll(numbers);

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`resize` resizes the vector, inserting default values for each of the items it needs to create for the new size. You want `reserve`.

Comment: @Kiran, not silly at all - I always have to stop and double-check myself when I want `reserve`. Similar names, similar functions will always cause confusion.

Answer (score 4):

```
numbers.resize(size);
```

This adds `size` 0's to the vector.

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < size; ++i ) {
    int r = (rand() % 10);
    numbers.push_back(r);
}
```

And this adds `size` random values to the vector.

Likely you wanted `reserve` not `resize`. `reserve` does not change the "visible" size of the vector it only changes the internal size of the storage used by the vector, `resize` however changes the "visible" size.